# Does this invoke undefined behaviour?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

Consider the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a =-1;
    unsigned b=-1;
    if(a==b)
        printf("%d %d",a,b);
    else
       printf("Unequal");
    return 0;
 }
```

In the line `printf("%d %d",a,b);`, `"%d"` is used to print an unsigned type.  Does this invoke undefined behavior and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although you are explicitly allowed to use the `va_arg` macro from `<stdarg.h>` to retrieve a parameter that was passed as an `unsigned` as an `int` (7.15.1.1/2), in the documentation for `fprintf` (7.19.6.1/9) which also applies to `printf`, it explicitly states that if any argument is not the correct type for the format specifier - for an unmodified `%d`, that is `int` - then the behaviour is not defined.

As @bdonlan notes in a comment, if the value of `b` (in this case `2^N - 1` for some `N`) is not representable in an `int` then it would be *undefined behavior* to attempt to access the value as an `int` using `va_arg` in any case. This would only work on platforms where the representation of an `unsigned` used at least one padding bit where the corresponding `int` representation had a sign bit.

Even in the case where the value of `(unsigned)-1` can be represented in an `int`, I still read this as being technically *undefined behavior*. As part of the implementation, it would seem to be allowed for an implementation to use built in magic instead of `va_args` to access the parameters to `printf` and if you pass something as an `unsigned` where an `int` is required then you have technically violated the contract for `printf`.

Comment: The exception in 7.15.1.1/2 reads as follows: "if
type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument [...], the behavior is undeﬁned, except [where] one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer
type, _and the value is representable in both types_" (emphasis mine). Since `-1` is not representable in both types, the behavior is undefined even without 7.19.6.1/9

Comment: @bdonlan: Technically `b` doesn't have the value `-1`, it has the value `2^N-1` for some `N`. Whether this value is representable in both an `int` and an `unsigned` is platform dependent - usually not, I grant you.

Comment: If a behavior is undefined only if some implementation-defined factor is true, then it's effectively undefined, as a conforming implementation is free to choose a value of INT_MAX and UINT_MAX that will allow it to summon nasal demons at the printf call in question.

Comment: @bdonlan: It's not "effectively undefined" because the implementation has to document `INT_MAX` and UINT_MAX` so it is possible to determine whether it's not UB for your particular implementation. Unless you meant something else by "effectively undefined"? It's not universally portable in any case.

Comment: What I mean is, a program cannot, typically, assume any specific semantics for it. Sure, you can do an `#if INT_MAX >= (UINT_MAX - 1)`, but, in practice, you might as well just assume it's always UB and be done with it

Comment: @bdonlan: Unless you're deliberately targeting only one or a few platforms, then yes, I agree with that.

Answer (score 2):

The standard isn't 100% clear on this point. On one hand, you get the specification for `va_arg`, which says (§7.15.1.1/2):

> If there is no actual next argument, or if
>   type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according
>   to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined, except for the following
>   cases:
>
> - one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer
>     type, and the value is representable in both types;
> - one type is pointer to void and the other is a pointer to a character type.

On the other hand, you get the specification of `printf` (§7.19.6.1/9):

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."

Given that it's pretty much a given that `printf` will retrieve arguments with `va_arg`, I'd say you're pretty safe with values that can be represented in the target type, but not otherwise. Since you've converted -1 to an unsigned before you pass it, the value will be out of the range that can be represented in a signed int, so the behavior will be undefined.

Comment: Except that (unsigned)-1 becomes (UINT_MAX - 1), which is usually beyond the range of INT_MAX...

Comment: I wonder if there are any implementations where use of `%X` and friends with signed values does anything other than show the hexadecimal representation of the underlying  bits?  If not, that would seem a useful behavior which should be provided for in the Standard, especially since a lot of existing code relies upon that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `if` will always evaluate to true and the `printf` will attempt to print an `unsigned` as a `signed`. Since the `signed` type may have trap representations, this may be UB if the sign representation is one's complement.