# Using printf function

Tags: c++, io

I've never bothered to look for printf as I started learning C++ without C. Now i want to use formatted output in some project. so I'm looking for some references that can explain the difference between using printf and IO streams.

One of my doubt are:

```
float f = 1.5;
printf("%d", f);
```

Why does it print zero? FWIK it should be reinterpreting float as int is that true?

Answer (score 7):

It actually invokes undefined behavior (UB). If the format specifier doesn't match with the *type* of the argument passed to `printf`, then it is UB, which means anything could happen. It can print `0`, or `9878978` or any garbage. Anything, entirely unpredictable, could happen.

Use `%f` if the data type of the argument is `float`.

Answer (score 4):

When you write `printf("%d", f);` the type of `f` must be int. The code as you have written it invokes undefined behaviour. Taken from [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851524/does-this-invoke-undefined-behaviour/5851578#5851578):

> in the documentation for fprintf (7.19.6.1/9) which also applies to printf, it explicitly states that if any argument is not the correct type for the format specifier - for an unmodified %d, that is int - then the behaviour is not defined.

---

> Why does it print zero?

Maybe they ran out of [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Because `%d` is for printing *integers,* not floats. You need one of the floating point format strings, like `%f`.

The usual conversions between data types don't work here because `printf` is a varargs-type function where you can basically push whatever you want onto the stack (or equivalent if your implementation is not stack-based) and, if it doesn't match what's in your format string, all bets are off - it's undefined behaviour.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424528/printf-of-a-size-t-variable-with-lld-ld-and-d-type-identifiers/2424554#2424554) for one of the things that can go wrong when you have such a mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you already have the answer, `%d` will print integer values only. Use "`%f`" which stands for float values . If you use `%f` you will get `1.500000`

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use %d format specifier ,then you better Type cast it Explicitly to avoid UB(Undefined Behavior ) to be called.

float f=1.5;
printf("%d",(int)f);