# Why the value of the variable is output 0?

Tags: c++, types, int, long-integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using printf function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783159/using-printf-function)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long long a=20;
    long long b=21;
    printf("%d %d",a,b);
}
```

Output: 20 0

Can anyone please explain this behavior?
[EDIT]
I know %d is not the right way to print long long But main objective of posting this question is I want to know the behaviour of long long such that it is printing 0 for b while the correct value for a.

Comment: %d is not the right way to print a `long long`.

Comment: Because you're using `printf` wrong (hint: note `%d` and the type of the variables)

Comment: Time to turn on some more warnings.  This question is a duplicate many times over.

Comment: I know I am doing %d.....I wanted to know why it is outputing this...

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. You can't find out "why" it's outputting this.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz that's quite untrue. Using a debugger you can absolutely find out why. You just can't trust that the same thing will happen on any *other* platform.

Comment: Well on a given implementation, you can probably go read the `printf` source and see what's happening.  It's unlikely to be completely random.

Comment: Why instead of giving an answer everyone is just downvoting????

Comment: I can ponder a guess. %d informs printf to expect 4 bytes.  By passing a long long, you are providing 8 bytes.  The first 4, since you are on a little endian system, correspond to the value of a, which is 20.  The last 4, since you are on a little endian system, are 0.  But it's undefined behavior, so I can't speak certainly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `long long` is a 64-bit type on your machine, while `int` is a 32-bit type.  You must also be on a little-endian machine.

Because `printf` is a variadic function, the only way it can know what types you passed to it is by how you label the arguments in the format string.  You are sending two 64-bit arguments, but only using two 32-but ones, according to your format string.  That means the first print is the lower 32-bit "bottom half" of your 64-bit `20`, and the second print is the 32-bit "top half" (which is, of course, `0`). The `21` you passed is completely ignored.

Comment: so it actually consider 64bit '20' as two 32-bits???

Comment: Yes, because that's what you told it to do.  This answer, of course, has many caveats, including that it may not even be applicable to other argument/format combinations.  Beware undefined behaviour, and certainly don't rely on it in your program.

Comment: ok... got it....I was just trying something to see how it actually behaves.... :)

Comment: this is one of many possible explanation. Sounds very likely (but could change in differetn machines, environments, etc. Even on another 64bit machine). Better to say that displaying a long with a printf expecting an int is not to be done, as it could do... anything, really.

Answer (score 3):

Pedantically speaking, your code invokes undefined behavior, because you've provided incorrect format specifier. You should use `%lld` instead of `%d`.

When it is undefined behavior, you cannot really reason out why it behaves like that. You may reason out for this input, but then that may fail for another set of input. Because it is undefined. Or you can see the documentation, it *might* say something about it, but it is *not required* to say anything why it is printing `0`.

Comment: try it doing %ld also....output wont change

Comment: @CarlNorum: Yes. It is `%lld`.

Comment: but i want to know why this is actually happening....I also know %lld can get long long printed....I mean what is the actual reason for long long value being printed zero when %d while the value of a is printing correctly???

Comment: @AbhimanyuSrivastava: When it is undefined behavior, you cannot really reason out why it behaves like that.

Comment: @Nawaz, given a specific implementation, you almost certainly can.

Comment: @CarlNorum: Yes, if you see their source code. But the implementation is *not required* to document the behavior.

Comment: Absolutely true - it may well be impossible.  But about 100% of the time, it isn't.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please specify the reason.

Comment: I just took back my upvote because @CarlNorum answer was more legimate and to the point of what I was expecting....

Comment: @AbhimanyuSrivastava, there's a real down vote, too.

Comment: that was not me.... no hard feeling... :)

Comment: @AbhimanyuSrivastava: My post answers your questions from the C++ Standard point of view, not from your point of view.

Comment: I will be looking for my expectations and I also specified that I know that %d is not the right choice...but still....And why u r bothered for one downvote??? look at my question...without knowing people just down voted it....it was not that bad... :P :P

Comment: @AbhimanyuSrivastava: It is not about downvote; it is about someone downvoting me without telling me how this answer can be improved. I am ALSO a learner.

Comment: +1 @Nawaz.  Unexplained downvotes are cowardly.