# Is this DWORD related code undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

It is my third attempt to clarify my confusion around this topic. But this time I have different question.

I have this code

```
  DWORD v1, v2, v3, Build;
  GetVersion(&v1, &v2, &v3, &Build);
  sprintf(VersionStr, "%d.%d.%d.%d", v1, v2, v3, Build);
```

which was written using Visual Studio maybe 10 years ago. I know `DWORD` is always `unsigned`-is this true?.

Now, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851524/does-this-invoke-undefined-behaviour), one of the answer cites some version of standard (does this standard version apply to my code?) which says about `va_arg`:

> The standard isn't 100% clear on this point. On one hand, you get the
>   specification for **va_arg**, which says (§7.15.1.1/2):
>
> If there is no actual next argument, or if type is not compatible with
>   the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the
>   default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined, except for
>   the following cases:
>
> one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the
>   corresponding unsigned integer type, **and the value is representable in
>   both types;**
>
> one type is pointer to void and the other is a pointer to a character
>   type.

On the other hand that answer also says about `printf`

> On the other hand, you get the specification of **printf** (§7.19.6.1/9):
>
> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
>   conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."

So first he cites quote about `va_arg` then about `printf`. It seems he is unclear too. Another answer mentions this violates `printf` contract anyway despite `va_arg` documentation. Please look at the thread. I am confused.

---

So my question is basically **is the code I presented undefined behaviour in any case**? Or for example **for values of `v1` which can be represented in `int`**, this is not undefined behaviour (as claimed in one of the answers I cited)?

Also can it be that since my code is old maybe for older versions of standard that is not undefined behaviour?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with reposing this question. Plus one. But there's no escaping the fact that the behaviour of your program is undefined.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I see but I also poster link to other answer which seems to claim this is safe

Comment: A careful read of the standard reveals it is not safe. You really ought to schedule a fix in your development stream.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Also what about the fact whether standard applies to my code, I mean if my code was old, and that UB was introduced in standard maybe recently?

Comment: Sadly not: even in my C university days (the 1990s), mismatching printf arguments was undefined.

Comment: Using the first comment on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5851578/4181011) and assuming that on your platform `std::is_same<DWORD, unsigned int>::value` evaluates to `true` and that `GetVersion` always returns values that are representable by both `int` and `unsigned int`: Then and only then this wouldn't be UB.

Comment: @user200312 What about the *"and the value is representable in both types"* part?

Comment: @SimonKraemer: That was about va_arg documentation

Comment: @user200312 That's not the problem. ` -1` for example can only be represented by the signed type, while `3000000` can only be represented by the unsigned type. For these values it would be undefined behaviour. The only valid range would be [0; 2^16-1]

Comment: @user200312 `printf`/`sprintf` uses `va_args`.

Comment: @SimonKraemer: Maybe, maybe not.  Some libraries implement `printf` in assembler, where there is no `va_arg`.

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree, yet most implementation I saw did. As OP mentioned `va_arg` himself/herself I think it is safe to assume we are talking about a `va_arg` version here, isn't it?

Comment: @SimonKraemer: OP mentioned [Jerry Coffin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5851646/103167) which mentioned `va_arg` rules.  But the accepted answer on that page is correct, the `printf` rules apply, not the `va_arg` rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really is quite simple: The format specifiers in `sprintf` **must** match the types of the arguments passed. Please don't try to conject exceptions to this rule.

Since a DWORD is an `unsigned long` and `%d` is **not** the correct format specifier for an `unsigned long`, the behaviour of your program is undefined. You **must** use `%lu`. Since `DWORD` is not a standard type you ought to include a line

```
static_assert(std::is_same<DWORD, unsigned long>::value, "DWORD is not an unsigned long");
```

somewhere in your program.

Comment: I think `DWORD` is guaranteed to be a 32 bits unsigned integer, so maybe better even to convert to `std::uint32_t` rather than using an `unsigned long`.

Comment: My MSVC platform has "typedef unsigned long DWORD;"

Comment: Yes, because `unsigned long` is exactly 32 bits in MSVC. It doesn't need to be so in GCC or any other compiler.

Comment: **No, no, no**. The size doesn't matter. `%d` is for `int`, `%lu` is for `unsigned long`. Even using `%d` for a `long` is UB! `long` might be 1's complement, `int` might be 2's complement, but the sizeof might be identical! Don't make these assumptions. Just fix the code.

Comment: I'd use a `std::stringstream` and `<<` rather than messing about with casting.

Answer (score 0):

`DWORD` is defined as an unsigned 32 bits integer [[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230318.aspx)].

`unsigned long` is guaranteed to be at least a 32 bits unsigned integer [[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)].

Therefore, you can always assign a `DWORD` to an `unsigned long` without loss of precision, so you can use the unsigned long specifier with `printf` and the likes along with an explicit conversion an the argument to unsigned long.

The alternative is that you use `std::uint32_t` which is guaranteed to be equal to `DWORD` and use that format specifier in `printf`.

Comment: I thought we already established that it's undefined behaviour. But ok, my answer does not address that directly, it only gives a means that would be standards compliant.

Comment: Another way of answering this question: if I can write a fully c++ standards compliant compiler that reformats your hard disk, eats your cat, or whatnot, if it encounters your code, however absurd that might be, then your program is undefined.